# Geolocation in VBA using Google Maps API

Tags: xml, google-maps, vba

So I was about to finish my geocoding script in VBA, but during beta tests I noticed that it cannot extract data for most of addresses, while for other it works perfectly. The code is as follows:

```
Sub newReadXMLData(link As String)
Dim odc As DOMDocument
Dim lat As String
Dim lng As String
Dim location As IXMLDOMElement
Dim locationPath As String
Dim i As Integer

Set odc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
odc.async = False
odc.Load (link)

locationPath = "GeocodeResponse/result/geometry[location_type='ROOFTOP']/location"
Set location = odc.SelectSingleNode(locationPath)

lat = GetTextValue(location, "./lat")
lng = GetTextValue(location, "./lng")

Debug.Print lat & "; " & lng

End Sub

Function GetTextValue(node As IXMLDOMElement, Optional xpath As String = "") As String
  Dim selectedNode As IXMLDOMElement

  If xpath <> "" And Not node Is Nothing Then
    Set selectedNode = node.SelectSingleNode(xpath)
  Else
    Set selectedNode = node
  End If

  If selectedNode Is Nothing Then
    GetTextValue = ""
  Else
    GetTextValue = Trim(selectedNode.Text)
  End If
End Function
```

The script returns correct values e.g. for `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+Santa+Clara,+California+95014&sensor=false`
but it does not return anything for e.g. `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=BAGIENNA+13,+88-100+INOWROCŁAW&sensor=false`. Could anyone explain why is that?

Comment: In what application are you running the VBA code and how do you pass the sample strings? I think it could be an encoding error. I get both of your strings to work correctly in a browser, but when I try your VBA code the second one returns `ZERO_RESULTS`. There's one character in INOWROCŁAW that doesn't seem to work in VBA (I tried it in Word 2010).

Comment: Actually maybe it's all about special characters... I'll check for that in a minute.
I'm running the script in Excel. I have a spreadsheet with addresses and a script that converst them into a google maps link.

Comment: IT WORKS! It was all about special characters in either city or street name. Thanks!

Comment: Great, posting an answer even though you already have! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be an encoding error. I get both of your strings to work correctly in a browser, but when I try your VBA code the second one returns `ZERO_RESULTS`. There's one character in *INOWROCŁAW* that doesn't seem to work in VBA (I tried it in Word 2010).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Olle Sjögren was right - the problem was caused by special characters in the address. A simple character conversion function does the job.